# This query show me with this active record

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having trouble getting two tables and passing them to controller:

IN A MODEL:

```
function get_all_entries() {
$query = $this->db->get('entry');
return $query->result();
$this->db->select('entry_id , count(comment_id) as total_comment');    
$this->db->group_by('entry_id');
$comment = $this->db->get('comment');
return $comment->result(); 
}
```

IN A CONTROLLER:

```
$data['query'] = $this->blog_model->get_all_entries(); 
$this->load->view('blog/index',$data);
```

How do I return `$query` and `$comment` variables to controller? I think I am doing it wrong.

Comment: once it return here return $query->result(); below code is not going to be get executed apply conditions what u want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this because you are not allowed to return twice in the same method

```
function get_all_entries() 
{
    $query  = $this->db->get('entry');
    $data[] = $query->result();

    $this->db->select('entry_id , count(comment_id) as total_comment');    
    $this->db->group_by('entry_id');
    $comment = $this->db->get('comment');
    $data[] =   $comment->result(); 
    return $data;
}
```

EDITS:

In controller

```
function index(){
    $this->load->model('mymodel');
    $result = $this->mymodel->get_all_entries();
    $entries = $result[0] ;
    $comments = $result[1] ;

    $data['entries'] =  $entries;
    $data['comments '] =  $comments;

}
```

Comment: How do i access it in controller : ? $data['data'] = $this->blog_model->get_all_entries();
$this->load->view('blog/index',$data);          ???

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you're returning `$query->result()` in first place, `return` function halts the current function, so the next steps are not being processed.

Best way would be to create two methods for either `$query` get and `$comment` get.

An alternative to your issue would be

```
function get_all_entries() {
    $query = $this->db->get('entry');
    $this->db->select('entry_id , count(comment_id) as total_comment');    
    $this->db->group_by('entry_id');
    $comment = $this->db->get('comment');
    return array($query->result(),$comment->result()); 
}
```

Then in your controller

```
list($data['query'],$data['comment']) = $this->blog_model->get_all_entries();
$this->load->view('blog/index',$data);
```

Comment: Alternative way didnt work How do i do this: Best way would be to create two methods for either $query get and $comment get.

Comment: What you mean by "didn't work" ? Error ? Wrong results ? Empty Array ? And I mean creating two methods into your Model. `function getEntries()` and `function getComments()`

Comment: How do i pass list($data['query'],$data['comment']) to view?

Comment: you need to pass the $data in your view file and then you can access it via $query and $comment.

Comment: Just do `$this->load->view('Yourview',$data)`

Comment: If the second query relies on data from the first one, splitting the method into two may not work.